# Downloading files

Tags: system, system-monitor

I'm about to download the program glances made at http://nicolargo.github.com/glances/ to monitor my computer. it offers a .zip file and a .tar.gz file. which file type is more compatible with ubuntu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both options are not very good if speaking about that particular program.

The preferred method would be to install the application from a PPA. Here's the instructions from the page you linked to:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:arnaud-hartmann/glances-stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install glances
```

The second preferred option is to install it as a Python package from Python's package repository:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python-pip build-essential python-dev
sudo pip install Glances
```

Downloading both `.zip` and `.tag.gz` will give you *source code* of the program, which, however, you should be able to install using

```
python setup.py install
```

after unpacking the archive file and `cd`-ing into the unpacked directory

Answer (score 1):

As a standard, .tar.gz is usually linux/unix based. I would go with that, but .zip is fine also.
Occasionally, you may find a site that has .tar.gz as the linux version and .zip as the Windows version; in that case, go with the .tar.gz

.tar.gz files, also known as "tar balls", can also offer a better compression ratio than .zip files.

[Here](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/tar1.html) is an online version of the man page if you're interested. In nautilus (the file manager), you just right click and say "extract here." It's a lot simpler than the tar command can be.